# How to strip newlines in jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I know about [strip_newlines](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/strip_newlines/) but it doesn't doing what I want:

```
{% capture string %}
Hello
there
{% endcapture %}

{{ string | strip_newlines }}
```

Outputs `Hellothere` but I need `Hello there` insead.

Replace doesn't working too, because you can't put newline char.

```
{{ string | replace: '\n', ' ' }}
```

How to replace all newlines with space? For example for usage in meta tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is trick:

```
{% assign description = page.excerpt | newline_to_br | strip_newlines | replace: '<br />', ' ' | strip_html | strip |  truncatewords: 30 %}

<meta name="description" content="{{ description }}">
```

Replace newlines with br tag, then strip newlines, and then replace `<br />` with space. Strip html and truncate for usage in meta description.

Comment: Does not work if you have some other `<br />` in your code that you wanna perserve.